# How to make CSS animation where button text on hover has extra bit that appears and moves into opposite direction

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I make such an effect / animation with CSS? Could be with JavaScript/jQuery as well, if pure CSS is not possible.

None of my searches so far gave me any reasonable hints (perhaps I just do not know what the right terms to use here).

It does not have to be exactly the same: even a partial similar effect would do.

The animation required:
[image]

Normal state: a button with red background & border; white text. Only "Add to Cart" text, centered.

[image]

On hover/focused state: button's background becomes white; text color becomes red (so they invert places), the small `>` appears and moves to the right; the button text moves to the left.

[image]

The same in a text form:

```
[   ADD TO CART   ] -- normal state
```

```
[ ADD TO CART   > ] -- hovered state
```

Using Bootstrap 5.1 as a base style in my attempts (do not think that it matters here though).

HTML code:

```html
<button class="btn btn-themed btn-effect text-uppercase"><span class="title">Add to Cart</span> <span class="extra">&gt;</span></button>
```

Base CSS:

```css
/* === THEMED BUTTONS === */
.btn-themed {
  border: 2px solid #ff1a0a;
  background-color: #ff1a0a;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.btn-themed:hover,
.btn-themed:focus {
  border: 2px solid #ff1a0a;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #ff1a0a;
}
/* === EFFECT ON BUTTON === */
.btn-effect span.extra {
  display: none;
}
.btn-effect:hover span.extra,
.btn-effect:focus span.extra {
  display: inline;
}
```

Here I'm hiding the bit with the `>` and showing it only on hover. This is to have the main button text to be fully centered (when a button in the "normal" state). On hover that bit shows up but:

1. It is jumpy (see the next image)
2. and most importantly: I have no idea how to position elements and what to apply to have them move as required.

[image]

I would really appreciate any hints / a working example on some existing website or even link to some JS library that can be used here etc.

Comment: You might be interested in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLfAW55_4cY).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul It's a different one ... but yes, it actually helped me as well. I had to do another effect on another button (where the whole button background instead of fading away needs to slide away) .. and it gave me the clue on how to solve it. here is the GIF of how it looks now: https://i.imgur.com/Y9jIXID.gif Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont do animations on display property.
Just add margin-right on text on hover. Thats all

```
.button:hover .text {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/VeterJS/pen/wvdRoKp

Comment: Sadly it does not tell me anything (I'm not a pro in CSS -- using it a few times per year only / general stuff)  . Can you post some code sample so I can see it in action / get the idea on what you mean here? P.S. I kind of understand that `display` and animations are not stacking well ... but I just had no other ideas right now.

Comment: @Vetter. Thanks a lot -- I've applied the code from your pen (after adjusting it to the actual HTML code/styles used here) and it works. Small downside: it's not super universal and looks a bit different depending on the actual button size. e.g. if button is `min-width: 12rem` it fits OK; but if it's `min-width: 10rem` then the button gets larger on hover. If I reduce the margin from `50px` to `30px` it now fits both but leaves a bit of a space on sides on larger button. But I see how it works and this is expected. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: This is how it looks after doing all that: https://i.imgur.com/9V11cYd.gif

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are looking for?

```css
/* === THEMED BUTTONS === */
.btn-themed {
  border: 2px solid #ff1a0a;
  background-color: #ff1a0a;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: .5s;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.btn-themed:hover,
.btn-themed:focus {
  border: 2px solid #ff1a0a;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #ff1a0a;  
}
/* === EFFECT ON BUTTON === */
.btn-themed span.extra {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1s ;
}

.btn-effect:hover span.extra,
.btn-effect:focus span.extra {
  visibility: visible;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-themed btn-effect text-uppercase"><span class="title">Add to Cart</span> <span class="extra">&gt;</span></button>
```

Comment: Yes, this one works as well (after making some modifications to have the initial text more centered (because when the extra symbol is not visible  it is still occupies the space and browser renders the button text more to the left). I have accepted the other answer though: he was first + as a newbee here he may need a rep more. Thanks a lot for your answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: This is how it looks after applying all the styles: https://i.imgur.com/9V11cYd.gif